# Как работать с таким массивом на php?

Tags: php

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Введите имя"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Введите фамилию"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Введите отчество"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Введите адрес"><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="men" value="мужчина" checked>мужчина<br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="women" value="женщина">женщина<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="robot" value="я не робот">я не робот<br><br>
        <select name="select[]" size="5" multiple>
            <option disabled selected>Какими языками владеете</option>
            <option value="французский">французский</option>
            <option value="русский">русский</option>
            <option value="английский">английский</option>
            <option value="немецкий">немецкий</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="filename" size=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

есть разметка html

от него я получаю вот такой массив

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => иван
    [lastname] => иванов
    [secondname] => иванович
    [address] => москва
    [men] => мужчина
    [robot] => я не робот
    [select] => Array
        (
            [0] => французский
            [1] => русский
            [2] => английский
            [3] => немецкий
        )

)
```

прогоняю через функцию что бы получить данные введены пользователем в таком формате Иван Иванов Иванович . т.д

Но не получается передать вложенный массив
и перебор вложенного масива функциями for, foreach, и.т.п не дает нужных результатов

Мне надо что-бы на выходе получалось вот это

```
    Array
(
    [firstname] => Иван
    [lastname] => Иванов
    [secondname] => Иванович
    [address] => Москва
    [men] => Мужчина
    [robot] => Я не робот
    [select] => Array
        (
            [0] => Французский
            [1] => Русский
            [2] => Английский
            [3] => Немецкий
        )

)
```

никаким образом не могу отдельно их получить что-бы работать с ним

```
[select] => Array
        (
            [0] => Французский
            [1] => Русский
            [2] => Английский
            [3] => Немецкий
        )
```

кто может помочь.

Я самоучка занимаюсь 1.2 месяца, на этой проблеме я несколько дней зациклился

Comment: что-то не вижу разницы в желаемом массиве

Comment: Я тут просто не дописал пару вещей, я потом с помощю str_replace заменяю символы, и каждый по отдельности сохраняю в txt и json, с этим у мегя проблем тоже не возникало, а вот выбраные языки пользователем, никак не подавались, потому что тупо не получадось с ними работать

Comment: Если вы хотите все элементы входящего массива рекурсивно обработать с помощью какой-то функции, то сделайте что-то вроде `array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$d){ $d = mb_strtoupper($d); })`

Comment: Вот теперь, все заработало))

Comment: оформил ответом, раз это то что надо было.

Comment: Я не знаю как оформить, куда нажать

Comment: Последний вопрос можно, создал функцию что-бы вывести данные введеные пользователем в отформатированом виде. Разбил все на массив с помощью метода explode вышло не очень, распечатал массив и получил каждому элементу отдельный массив вот так: array([0] => Иван) потом array([0] => Иванов) и т.д. как это объединить в один массив

Comment: приведите ваш код наконец

Comment: <?php
$arr = ["ivan", "petrov", ["eng", "due"]];

function test_print($item)
{
    $item = strtoupper($item);
    replaceUser($item);
}

function replaceUser($arr){
  $arr = str_replace(['U','u'],['У','у'],$arr);
  $arr = explode(",",$arr);
  print_r($arr);
 // display($arr);
}


function display($array){
  echo " имя:". $array[0] . " отчество: " . $array[1] . " языки: " . $array[2] . " | " .$array[3];
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print');

Comment: а зачем вам от именованных ключей перешли к индексам?

Comment: Я перевел введеные данные в заглавные буквы, и хочу их вывести в отформатированном виде, мне без разнцицы как выводить элементы массива, хоть именованные хоть индексные, каким то образом когда я методом explode разбиваю на массив, то каждому элементу создаеться отдельный массив с индексными ключами 0.. не пойми не правильно я не дурак, основы знаю, методы знаю, а вот с вложенными массивами тупик....просто запусти код который я скинул, и поймешь о чем я

Answer (score 1):

хрустальный шар подсказал, что намереваетесь обойти рекурсивно весь массив и применить к нему нечто вроде `mb_strtoupper`, так что с этой целью можно использовать примерно следующий код:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$d){  
    $d = mb_strtoupper($d); 
});
```

обратите внимание, что аргумент в функцию обратного вызова передается по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обрабатывать этот массив отдельно:

```
$cnt = count($array['select']); // Определяем количество выбранных языков
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
 // Тута делаем, что нужно
 // Для обращения к элементу используйте: $array['select'][$i]
}
```

Если же вы хотите заключить этот код в свой цикл foreach, то можно сделать вот так:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if(is_array($array[$key])) { // Если $array[$key] является массивом, то это наши языки
  $cnt = count($array[$key]) // Определяем количество выбранных языков
  for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
   // Тута делаем, что нужно
   // Для обращения к элементу используйте: $array[$key][$i]
  }
 }
 else { // А если это не массив, значит это не языки
  // Тут ваш код обработки всего остального
 }
}
```

В данном случае языки находились во вложенном массиве 'select'. Более подробно про многомерные массивы можно прочитать тут: https://metanit.com/php/tutorial/2.16.php
либо введя "Многомерные массивы" в поисковик.

Comment: Благодарю, посмотрю что из этого получится

Comment: Эту статью я тоже читал, но это было не то что нужно